# How send '+' instead '%20; while space appears

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I faced an issue. When I send a Json file on Ajax request, all parameters appear on URL in a proper format, except Strings with whitespaces. I received '%20' and interesting to receive '+'.
What shall I do?

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: myUrl,
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
        //Do thomething
      },
      error: function () {
      }
});
```

data its Json format, like :

```
  data
  {
    param1:1,
    param2:2,
    param3:"Hello world"
  }
```

On URL displayed

```
   &param1=1&param2=2&param3=Hello%20world
```

and desire results should be :

```
   &param1=1&param2=2&param3=Hello+world
```

Regards.

Comment: Decoding url you'll find space on there

Comment: As ^^^ said, a proper server should decode both + and %20 into a space when it parses the request.  How it is passed should be invisible to you.

Comment: In my case, I can't change server's configurations. It doesn't accept ' %20'. Only '+'

Comment: @Evgeny Eww, that's a very non-conforming server (or application that uses a less than ideal method to obtain the request path) :}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `jQuery.param` and `String.prototype.replace` to achieve so:

First, convert you object to a serialized representation for query string using:

```
var params = jQuery.param(data);
```

then, replace all the `%20` with `+` using `String.prototype.replace`:

```
params = params.replace('%20', '+');
```

Read more about [jQuery.param](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) and [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Hope it helps.

```js
var params = jQuery.param({
  param1: 1,
  param2: 2,
  param3: "Hello world"
}).replace('%20', '+');

console.log(params);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Works